# How To Grouping Array Data With Date From Ajax Response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have array data like this

```
[{ 
   date: "January 2019",
   sum: 20,
   name: "Persada",
},{ 
   date: "Februay 2019",
   sum: 21,
   name: "Persada",
},{ 
   date: "April 2019",
   sum: 22,
   name: "Persada",
},{ 
   date: "January 2019",
   sum: 10,
   name: "Kharisma",
},{ 
   date: "March 2019",
   sum: 5,
   name: "Kharisma",
},{ 
   date: "Februari 2019",
   sum: 4,
   name: "Solusindo",
},{ 
   date: "Mai 2019",
   sum: 2,
   name: "Solusindo",
}]
```

From the data above, I have chosen a different date. so I get a date like this

```
["January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "Mai 2019"]
```

and then i want to set data like this

```
[{
   date : ["January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "Mai 2019"],
   sum: [20, 21, 0, 22, 0],
   name: "Persada",
},{
   date : ["January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "Mai 2019"],
   sum: [0, 0, 10, 5, 0],
   name: "Kharisma",
},{
   date : ["January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "Mai 2019"],
   sum: [0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
   name: "Solusindo",
}]
```

if there is no data on that date, then the data sum will automatically be replaced by 0. please help me to set data like that. thank you

Comment: I find it far more useful to return the data in the correct format from the server / databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. extract unique dates from response (used `Set`, `Array.from` to create an initial entries)
2. create a dictionary from initial date entries (used `Object.entries` to create dictionary form array)
3. using `Array.prototype.reduce` create a dictionary of `date and sum` with `name` as key
4. used `Object.entries` to loop through the dictionary to create the result set.
5. used `Object.keys` to extract `dates` from the date dictionary
6. used `Object.values` to extract `sum` from the date dictionary

```js
const response = [{
  date: "January 2019",
  sum: 20,
  name: "Persada",
}, {
  date: "Februay 2019",
  sum: 21,
  name: "Persada",
}, {
  date: "April 2019",
  sum: 22,
  name: "Persada",
}, {
  date: "January 2019",
  sum: 10,
  name: "Kharisma",
}, {
  date: "March 2019",
  sum: 5,
  name: "Kharisma",
}, {
  date: "Februari 2019",
  sum: 4,
  name: "Solusindo",
}, {
  date: "Mai 2019",
  sum: 2,
  name: "Solusindo",
}];

const initialValues = Array.from(new Set(response.map(({date}) => date)), date => [date, 0]);

const dictionary = response.reduce((acc, {
  date,
  sum,
  name
}) => {
  acc[name] = acc[name] || Object.fromEntries(initialValues);

  acc[name][date] = (acc[name][date] || 0) + sum;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(dictionary).map(([name, sumByDate]) => ({
  date: Object.keys(sumByDate),
  sum: Object.values(sumByDate),
  name
}));


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Build an Object with unique keys as `name` and values of sum, date, name.

2) Go over data with `forEach` loop, if the key does not exist then add the default values of `sum` with array of '0's with array size of dates.

3) Update the respective `sum` value.

4) In the function return the Object values of `res` as an array.

```js
const update = data => {
  const dates = [
    "January 2019",
    "February 2019",
    "March 2019",
    "April 2019",
    "Mai 2019"
  ];
  // Alternatively get the dates like
  // const dates = [...new Set(data.map(({date}) => date))];
  const sums = dates.map(x => 0);
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(({ name, sum, date }) => {
    if (!res[name]) {
      res[name] = { date: [...dates], sum: [...sums], name };
    }
    const index = dates.findIndex(month => month === date);
    if (index !== -1) {
      res[name]["sum"][index] = sum;
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const data = [
  {
    date: "January 2019",
    sum: 20,
    name: "Persada"
  },
  {
    date: "Februay 2019",
    sum: 21,
    name: "Persada"
  },
  {
    date: "April 2019",
    sum: 22,
    name: "Persada"
  },
  {
    date: "January 2019",
    sum: 10,
    name: "Kharisma"
  },
  {
    date: "March 2019",
    sum: 5,
    name: "Kharisma"
  },
  {
    date: "Februari 2019",
    sum: 4,
    name: "Solusindo"
  },
  {
    date: "Mai 2019",
    sum: 2,
    name: "Solusindo"
  }
];

console.log(update(data));
```